# Print out first line of input file char by char, but nothing comes to screen

Tags: c, pointers

So Im trying to print out the first line of a file thats being passed in lets say its a plain text file with a couple of words in the first line.

I open the file and pass it through a function that does some work on the file called process. This little bit of work if for debugging reason , because my ultimate goal is to read in the entire text file line my line and process each line and reverse the words in that line.

But im stuck here i run the program with a text file argument and i get nothing in return and i know my logic sounds right i think? I just want this to ultimately printout every character in that line. Then eventually put all those characters in a char array or char instream[500]

Can someone tell me what iam doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void process(FILE *infile);

int main(int argc, char  *argv[])
{
    int i;
    FILE *fp;

    printf("argc = %d\n",argc);

    for(i = 1 ; i <= argc; i++)
    {
        fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
        if(fp == NULL)
        {
            printf("The file: %s doesnt exist.\n", argv[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The file: %s does exist \n",argv[i]);
            process(fp);
        } 
    }

    return 0;
}


void process(FILE *infile)
{
    int k =0;
    char iochar;
    char instream[500];

    while((iochar = getc(infile)) != '\n')
    {
        printf("Hi there %c", iochar );  // nothing prints out here why not??
        //instream[k++] = iochar;
    }  
}
```

Comment: `iochar` should be an `int`.. and the first `for` loop should be `for(i = 1 ; i < argc; i++)`

Comment: What happens if you terminate the `printf` format string with a new line? Or print a new line at the end of `process`. (Also: Close your file when you are done reading. And you should also check the `getc` result for `EOF`, to catch the case where you don't have a new-line character in your file.)

Comment: and make sure your input file is not empty

Comment: Additional : close the file once read.